# Split in Ramakrsna Mission history

Tags: ramakrishna

Jai Sri Sri Sarada Ramakrsna ki jai!

Why did a split occur between Ganendra brahmachari & Sw Nirmalananda from the others as described by Sw. Gambhirananda's "History of the Ramakrishna Math and Mission"? A split is talked about, but no reason is given as to why this happened. We hear a little bit about some issues with Udbhodan House, but this is after the fact of factions and desires to split.

Comment: Since, you are referencing a book, you can mention the pg. numbers too for making it a better question and helping the answerers.

Comment: It is mentioned in the chapter entitled, A New Order in Travail (pp 285-312). We read about various groups affiliated but unincorporated with the Math and Mission. Senior monks either were passing away or some went off and became "out of touch", as Sw. Gambirananda speaks of Sw. Abhedananda (who also created a separate organization). We read of the earlier mentioned personas causing trouble but we don't know what led to additional splits. The personas came out of the existing factions. Some factions probably split due to different views of Sri Mā & Thakurji.

Comment: Nice, thanks. You can add this info to the question too if you wish.